# Sqlite quote returns null

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I have the following SQLite call in my code in which Summary is returned as null.

```
String query = "SELECT quote(Summary), Description, DateCollected, Location, HowCollected, Picture FROM Pennies" + orderbyclause[(int)order].ToString();

Task<IEnumerable<Item>> myItems;
myItems = Task.Run(() => database.QueryAsync<Item>(query).Result.AsEnumerable());
```

If I remove the call to quote, it returns the proper data string (in this case "My first penny".)

```
String query = "SELECT Summary, Description, DateCollected, Location, HowCollected, Picture FROM Pennies" + orderbyclause[(int)order].ToString();
```

Should the previous call work or am I misunderstanding what quote() does?

Comment: The first call should work. It might be a Xamarin issue. You probably can try `quote("Summary")` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: try `quote(Summary) as 'Summary'` - I think the problem is that `quote` does not return a Column name that SQLite.net can map to your data model

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Sadly neither worked. But they were worth the try.

Comment: I make a test use above sql, it worked in the DB Browser for sqlite, I can get the result by this sql, This issue is related to the SQLite.net. You can open an issue to this Github link about his nuget package.https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues